# Linux Cloud/Windows On Prem Deployments

Tags: docker, deployment, linux, windows

I have sort of a unique problem where I have a cloud deployment (linux) that needs to be ported to an on-premise deployment (windows).

The constraint is that this is medical software and hospitals often do not support linux on-premise. The application is written mostly in golang, which can be compiled for Windows, but the application also talks to a Redis instance, which seems to have spotty Windows support. Furthermore, the software would likely need to be installed by a less-technical admin user due to adversarial relationships between hospital IT and individual clinic fiefdoms.

It seems like HyperV might be a good fit for deploying the cloud app onto Windows 10 clinic PCs on-premise with minimal changes, but it is possible to make an installer to do this with minimal user interaction? Seems like Hyper-V requires a lot of technical knowledge and menu navigation to setup. Are there any tools or services that might facilitate this? Other options I haven't thought of?

Comment: I'm guessing your solution is a private cloud one? What I usually do when I have to portate solutions from one OS to another is to use solutions like [AWS AppStream](https://aws.amazon.com/appstream2/): customers only have to launch their browser to use the app.